# Java Simple English Calculator, output issue

Tags: java, calculator

I am writing a calculator program that takes inputs from 0-9 and outputs the results in both numerical from and in plain english (Ex: Two plus three equals 5). I have gotten it to be able to print out the result in words but I am now stuck on how to get it to print out the original problem in numerical form. The output must include both the result in numbers and in words.

The numbers have already been converted into strings through a switch statement but is there anyway I can print out the original problem? If not would I have to completely restructure this instead? Any help would be appreciated I have been stuck on this for a while now.

Here is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Project {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        char operation;
        int num1, num2;

        //Asks for user to input first number
        System.out.println("Please enter the first number (0-9)");
        num1 = input.nextInt();

        //Asks user for an operation
        System.out.println("Please enter the type of operation that you would like to perform");
        operation = input.next().charAt(0);

        //Asks user to input the second number
        System.out.println("Please enter the second number (0-9)");
        num2 = input.nextInt();


        //Limits the numbers to the range of 0-9 
        if(num1 > 9 || num2 > 9){

            System.out.println("Invalid Digit!!");
        System.exit(0);}

        //An array that converts number into a string
        String num[] = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};
        switch(operation){

            case '-': //Subtraction conversion
                System.out.println(num[num1]+" minus "+num[num2] + " is " + (num1-num2));
                break;

            case '+':   //Addition conversion
                System.out.println(num[num1]+" plus "+num[num2] + " is " + (num1+num2));
                break;   

            case '*':   //Multipication conversion
                System.out.println(num[num1]+" multiplied by "+num[num2] + " is " + (num1*num2));
                break;

            case '/': //Division conversion
                System.out.println(num[num1]+" divided by "+num[num2] + " is " + (num1/num2));
                break;

            case '^':   //Exponentiation conversion

                if(num2 == 0){ //checks to see if the second number entered is 0

                System.out.println("Error: Cannot divide by Zero"); //Divide by Zero error message
                break;}

                System.out.println(num[num1]+" to the power of "+num[num2] + " is " + Math.pow(num1,num2));
                break;

            default:
        System.out.println("Error: Invalid Operation Entered"); }


    }
}
```

Comment: You still have the original numbers. Use them.

Comment: Do you mean you want to output something like `2+3=5`?

Comment: Hello, cannot you print `num1 + operation + num2`?  Btw, you check for division by 0 in wrong place.

Comment: `System.out.println(num1+" - "+num2 + " = " + (num1-num2));` and so on?

Comment: Yes I need it output something like that in addition the current output which is in words.

Comment: Then just put that in the next line? I don't get what is the problem here.

Comment: do you want output like `two plus three equals five` ? Right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very simple, I think you are getting confused. Consider following points:

- You have original numbers saved in `num1` and `num2`, so if you want to show the original numbers in integer form, then just use `num1` instead of `num[num1]`
- You are checking for `zero division` when finding exponent. You should shift this check to division case.

Replace your `switch` like this:

```java
switch(operation){

    case '-': //Subtraction conversion
        System.out.println(num[num1]+" minus "+num[num2] + " is " + (num1-num2));
        System.out.println(num1+" - "+num2 + " = " + (num1-num2));
        break;

    case '+':   //Addition conversion
        System.out.println(num[num1]+" plus "+num[num2] + " is " + (num1+num2));
        System.out.println(num1+" + "+num2 + " = " + (num1+num2));
        break;   

    case '*':   //Multipication conversion
        System.out.println(num[num1]+" multiplied by "+num[num2] + " is " + (num1*num2));
        System.out.println(num1+" * "+num2 + " = " + (num1*num2));
        break;

    case '/': //Division conversion
        if(num2 == 0){ //checks to see if the second number entered is 0

            System.out.println("Error: Cannot divide by Zero"); //Divide by Zero error message
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(num[num1]+" divided by "+num[num2] + " is " + (num1/num2));
        System.out.println(num1+" / "+num2 + " = " + (num1/num2));
        break;

    case '^':   //Exponentiation conversion
        System.out.println(num[num1]+" to the power of "+num[num2] + " is " + Math.pow(num1,num2));
        System.out.println(num1+" ^ "+num2 + " = " + Math.pow(num1,num2));
        break;

    default:
        System.out.println("Error: Invalid Operation Entered"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See if the below print statements helps

```
case '-': //Subtraction conversion
            System.out.println(num[num1]+" minus "+num[num2] + " is " + (num1-num2));
            System.out.println(num1+" "+operation + "  "+num2+ "="+(num1 - num2));
            break;

case '+':   //Addition conversion
            System.out.println(num[num1]+" plus "+num[num2] + " is " + (num1+num2));
            System.out.println(num1+" "+operation + "  "+num2+ "="+(num1 + num2));  
            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

is it this what you are looking for? for example for 9 + 9 your output will be:

> nine plus nine is 18
>  9 +  9 = 18

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Project {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        char operation;
        int num1, num2;

        //Asks for user to input first number
        System.out.println("Please enter the first number (0-9)");
        num1 = input.nextInt();

        //Asks user for an operation
        System.out.println("Please enter the type of operation that you would like to perform");
        operation = input.next().charAt(0);

        //Asks user to input the second number
        System.out.println("Please enter the second number (0-9)");
        num2 = input.nextInt();


        //Limits the numbers to the range of 0-9 
        if(num1 > 9 || num2 > 9){

            System.out.println("Invalid Digit!!");
        System.exit(0);}

        //An array that converts number into a string
        String num[] = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};
        switch(operation){

            case '-': //Subtraction conversion
                System.out.println(num[num1]+" minus "+num[num2] + " is " + (num1-num2));
                System.out.println(num1+" "+operation + "  "+num2+ " = "+(num1 - num2)); 
                break;

            case '+':   //Addition conversion
                System.out.println(num[num1]+" plus "+num[num2] + " is " + (num1+num2));
                System.out.println(num1+" "+operation + "  "+num2+ " = "+(num1 + num2)); 
                break;   

            case '*':   //Multipication conversion
                System.out.println(num[num1]+" multiplied by "+num[num2] + " is " + (num1*num2));
                System.out.println(num1+" "+operation + "  "+num2+ " = "+(num1 * num2)); 
                break;

            case '/': //Division conversion
                System.out.println(num[num1]+" divided by "+num[num2] + " is " + (num1/num2));
                System.out.println(num1+" "+operation + "  "+num2+ " = "+(num1 / num2)); 
                break;

            case '^':   //Exponentiation conversion

                if(num2 == 0){ //checks to see if the second number entered is 0

                System.out.println("Error: Cannot divide by Zero"); //Divide by Zero error message
                break;}

                System.out.println(num[num1]+" to the power of "+num[num2] + " is " + Math.pow(num1,num2));
                System.out.println(num1+" "+operation + "  "+num2+ " = "+(Math.pow(num1,num2))); 
                break;

            default:
        System.out.println("Error: Invalid Operation Entered"); }


    }
}
```